# Read timeout on a web service, but the operation still completes?

Tags: java, web-services, networking, soap, timeout

I have a Java web service client running on Linux (using Axis 1.4) that invokes a series of web services operations performed against a Windows server. There are times that some transactional operations fail with this Exception:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

However, the operation on the server is completed (even having no useful response on the client). Is this a bug of either the web service server/client? Or is expected to happen on a TCP socket?

Comment: If you set read timeout on the socket, then this is expected behaviour. Try to configure your underlying socket so that it doesn't timeout while waiting for response. I don't know how to do that in Axis though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, rather than a bug.  The operation behind the web service doesn't know anything about your read timing out so continues processing the operation.

You could increase the timeout of the connection - if you are manually manipulating the socket itself, the socket.connect() method can take a timeout (in milliseconds).  A zero should avoid your side timing out - see the API docs.

If the operation is going to take a long time in each case, you may want to look at making this asynchronous - a first request submits the operations, then a second request to get back the results, possibly with some polling to see when the results are ready.

If you think the operation should be completing in this time, have you access to the server to see why it is taking so long?

Comment: The server really isn't under my control. I guess i'll have to catch those read timeout exceptions and try to query the WS if the operation succeeded. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. We have JAX-WS soap webservice running on Jboss EAP6 (or JBOSS 7). The default http socket timeout is set to 60 seconds unless otherwise overridden in server or by the client. To fix this issue I changed our java client to something like this.  I had to use 3 different combinations of propeties here

This combination seems to work as standalone java client or webservice client running as part of other application on other web server.

```
//Set timeout on the client
String edxWsUrl ="http://www.example.com/service?wsdl";

URL WsURL = new URL(edxWsUrl);
EdxWebServiceImplService  edxService = new EdxWebServiceImplService(WsURL);
EdxWebServiceImpl edxServicePort = edxService.getEdxWebServiceImplPort();
//Set timeout on the client
BindingProvider edxWebserviceBindingProvider  = (BindingProvider)edxServicePort;
BindingProvider edxWebserviceBindingProvider  = (BindingProvider)edxServicePort;

edxWebserviceBindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout", connectionTimeoutInMilliSeconds);
edxWebserviceBindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout", connectionTimeoutInMilliSeconds);

edxWebserviceBindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout", connectionTimeoutInMilliSeconds);
edxWebserviceBindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout", connectionTimeoutInMilliSeconds);

edxWebserviceBindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout", connectionTimeoutInMilliSeconds);
edxWebserviceBindingProvider.getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout", connectionTimeoutInMilliSeconds);
```